# Track WPF Grid Column Width Upon Resizing

Tags: wpf

I am using Grid splitter to resize columns in wpf application. I want some event that occurs when I am done with resizing. Grid Splitter has no events in it.

So I try using events from grid columns

```
  void col_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _dragStart = true;
        _currentColWidth = (sender as ColumnDefinition).ActualWidth;

    }

    bool _dragStart;
    double _currentColWidth;
    void col_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _dragStart = false;
        if ((sender as ColumnDefinition).ActualWidth != _currentColWidth)
        {

        }
    }
```

This is the screenshot of the application and these are the two columns with and without resizing

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean with GridSplitter doesn't have any events ?

XAML

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column1" Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column2" Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<GridSplitter x:Name="GridSplitter1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" DragCompleted="GridSplitter1_DragCompleted" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="0" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Width="2"/>
```

CODE:

```
 void GridSplitter1_DragCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        void GridSplitter1_DragCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Column1 : " + Column1.Width + "\n" + "Column2: " + Column2.Width);
    }
    }
```

[image]

Works very fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Bind the gridsplitter position (or some width in the column) against a property. In the Binding use the delay option (new in .NET 4.5)

This was introduced for Slider-Controls, etc. which update much too often. Set the delay to a few hundred milliseconds, then you only get the final updated value.

See more here: http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/21/wpf-4-5-part-4-the-new-bindings-delay-property/